# I have .frm files of tables but they do not show up in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have copied database folder from wamp/bin/mysql/data

and then reinstalled the windows

Now I have pasted them back into their folder. As I open the phpMyAdmin, I see the database name, but when I click on them it is empty, as if no table has been created in them.

Where are my tables now? thanks

Comment: Why didn't you dump the database?  O.o

Comment: EDIT: @dan means You should of exported the database via PMA (PhpMyAdmin) or such tool, then imported the DB via the same option you exported.

Comment: @Mostafa. Is your wamp version same as previous. I think it should work if u have same same version and replaced new data folder with previous. I don't know the solution with changed version. :)

Comment: no it is not the same as the previous version

Comment: If this is a MYISAM tabe then there are 3 files that constitute a complete table. xxx.frm, xxx.MYD, xxx.MYI. Do you have all three files for each of your tables. Also if you have changed versions of MYSQL you will probably have to upgrade your tables to the new version `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html`